# SQLite does not create a table in Flask application

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have written a test Flask script that only prints hello world to the screen, which works fine. Now I decided to test the SQLite database by first creating the database tables. However, it seems create_all create the database with no errors but .tables does not return any table.

Following is my code and structure of package:

```
     Run_test.py
│
└───Test
    │   Model_test.py
    │   requirements.txt
    │   site_test.db
    │   views.py
    │   __init__.py
```

**init**.py is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand



app_test = Flask(__name__)
app_test.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456789'
app_test.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site_test.db'  
app_test.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db_test = SQLAlchemy(app_test)

migrate_test = Migrate(app_test, db_test)   
manager_test= Manager(app_test)
manager_test.add_command('db_test',MigrateCommand)

login_manager_test= LoginManager(app_test) 
login_manager_test.login_view = 'login'
login_manager_test.login_message_category = 'info'
```

The following is also  Model_test.py:

```
from Test import db_test,app_test, login_manager_test
from flask_login import UserMixin,current_user



@login_manager_test.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db_test.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db_test.Column(db_test.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db_test.Column(db_test.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.name}')"
```

This is also Run_Test.py :

```
from Test import app_test
from Test import views
from Test import Model_test
if __name__ == "__main__":   
    app_test.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

I did not include views.py since it has only one function and prints hello world to screen. I can see hello world successfully on the screen.

However when I go to python and type:

```
 from Test import db_test
 db_test.create_all()
```

I can create a database file successfully

but when I do

```
sqlite3 site_test.db
.tables
```

I get nothing and I don't get my table back.

I really appreciate if anyone can explain to me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `db_test` from **Model_test.py** file.

```
from Model_test import db_test
db_test.create_all()
```

Comment: Why ? I am importing it from Test, which in turn will import it from __init__.py